# What React Lifecycle method should I use to check auth state in react navigation TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, redux-persist

I am building a react native element. The element will have 3 `react-navigation` **TabNavigator** as follows:

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
      login: { screen: LoginPage },
      signup: { screen: SignupPage },
      main: { screen: HomePage},
    },
    {
      navigationOptions: {
        //tabBarVisible: false, // comment out for testing
      },
      lazyLoad: true
    });
```

My HomePage is checking the **auth** on `componentDidMount`

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { isAuthenticated, navigation } = this.props;
    console.log("home isAutenticated???>>", isAuthenticated);
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      navigation.navigate('login');
    }
  }

  .....
}
```

All the auth flow works fine until I enabled tabBar to be visible. When I click the home tab even after I log out, the homePage still show, without triggering the `componentDidMount` logic, makes me wonder if I should put the auth checking logic in some other lifecycle method? if so, which one?

Comment: Components in tab are not remounted on every navigation. Also, why are you using a tab navigator for non-auth and auth pages? Use a switch navigator for the login flow then show the user a tab navigator for authed routes.

Comment: You are right on. The switch navigator is the right way to go. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html If you write an answer I will accept it. @Li357